# How can I convert Quary string which are sent as Kebab Case to Pascal Case

Tags: c#, .net

The query strings that are sent from the client side to api are in the form of kabab case

```
?deal-type=sale&property-type=apartment
```

I have a property for each of these query strings, which is an attribute
**BindProperty** is used to bind but I don't want the properties to be kabab Case, I want them to be written Pascal Case.

```
public class PropertiesController : Controller
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string DealType { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }   

    [HttpGet]
    public object Data()
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

I know how to use the **Name** property in **BindProperty**. This possibility exists separately for each one. But this is not my problem.
Is it possible to solve this problem, for example, in **middleWare** or with the help of **ConfigureServices** in Startup?

Comment: Which version of asp.net are you using? and why you are inheriting from controller? pleae post complete code of your action method

Comment: "The query strings that are sent from the client side to api are in the form of kabab case" maybe tell the client to send the correct strings?

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh im use .net 7
and Controller is a class that inherits from controllerBase .net

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @Charlieface
This was a team decision made based on the documentation of the studies for seo

Comment: @MohammadMiras I know what a `controller` is. I meant that you should not define your `DTO` inside a `controller` and you should use a separate `class`  or `record` for it,Before starting coding , you should learn it well. start to snake Your code has many flaws that show your lack of familiarity with `C#` and `ASP.NET Core`.